# Configure AWS with Apache Virtualhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, elastic-beanstalk

I have **Route 53** configured to forward

```
client1.mydomain.com ALIAS -> eb.crypticaddress.com.
```

This works as expected. Now I have in Elastic Beanstalk the possibility to override Apache Config.

On the EB Instance I have a NodeJS running providing an API but also serving out static Website Content as gGood ol' static HTML and JQuery.

**app.js**

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'website')));`

**Static Folders**

website/client1
website/client2
website/client3

How can I wire this up, so that

`client1.mydomain.com` is forwarded to `website/client1` folder and so forth ?

I already have this nginx.config file in a .ebextensions folder in the project.

I am using this inside the .ebextensions folder:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      NameVirtualHost *:80

      <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/app/current/website"
         <Directory "/var/app/current/website">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
         </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>

      <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName client1.mydomain.com
       DocumentRoot "/var/app/current/website/client1"
        <Directory "/var/app/current/website/client1">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
        </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>
```

But EB is ignoring my file...

Comment: It's probably because httpd is already started by the time the file is placed.

Comment: @jordanm - that's a very good idea. GG.